# How can I set Emacs up for iOS development with Swift?

Tags: osx, development, ios

I'm going to be doing a bit of iOS work soon, using Swift (yay!). Unfortunately, this usually involves xcode (boo!).

How can I set Emacs up to build iOS apps with Swift? Ideally, they would run on my testing device automatically. More advanced functionality like autocomplete would be nice too, but not critical.

Comment: Did you google "emacs swift"? Download the mode. Install. Compiling is the same as any compilation - use make or xcodebuild or etc. It is not iOS specific. Getting compiled apps to run on your test device is a different question and probably not appropriate for this site.

Comment: Batsov made a swift-mode, but not really sure how to get stuff like the emulator working.

Comment: I recommend this site: [Emacs and Xcode](http://roupam.github.io/)

Comment: Just found that [one](https://github.com/iamleeg/swift-mode). Never used it myself.

Answer (score 3):

There's [swift-mode](https://github.com/chrisbarrett/swift-mode) which is available on [MELPA](http://melpa.milkbox.net/). This offers:

- Syntax highlighting
- Indentation
- Code navigation with imenu
- Syntax checking with [flycheck](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck)

There's [another swift-mode here](https://github.com/iamleeg/swift-mode), but it looks less complete.

To run code on the device, your best option is probably calling [fruitstrap](https://github.com/roupam/fruitstrap) from Emacs ([discussed here](http://roupam.github.io/#sec-5)).